# I am trying to read Arduino data using Serialport module but module is not working

Tags: node.js, node-serialport

I receive the following error trace:

```
C:\Users\Maaz\Desktop\FYP Project\Server\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:96
  throw err
  ^

Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → C:\Users\Maaz\Desktop\FYP Project\Server\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\build\bindings.node
 → C:\Users\Maaz\Desktop\FYP Project\Server\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\build\Debug\bindings.node
 → C:\Users\Maaz\Desktop\FYP Project\Server\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\build\Release\bindings.node
 → C:\Users\Maaz\Desktop\FYP Project\Server\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\out\Debug\bindings.node
 → C:\Users\Maaz\Desktop\FYP Project\Server\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\Debug\bindings.node
 → C:\Users\Maaz\Desktop\FYP Project\Server\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\out\Release\bindings.node
 → C:\Users\Maaz\Desktop\FYP Project\Server\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\Release\bindings.node
 → C:\Users\Maaz\Desktop\FYP Project\Server\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\build\default\bindings.node
 → C:\Users\Maaz\Desktop\FYP Project\Server\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\compiled\8.11.1\win32\x64\bindings.node
    at bindings (C:\Users\Maaz\Desktop\FYP Project\Server\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:93:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Maaz\Desktop\FYP Project\Server\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\lib\win32.js:1:98)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Maaz\Desktop\FYP Project\Server\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\lib\index.js:6:22)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```